# Calculate size of text (text rectangle) rendered with GDI

Tags: winapi, text, menu, gdi, font-size

I'm trying to create a menu and draw it with GDI.

I have a MENU TITLE, unchangable.
I have an array of items.

If I want the title to be "MAIN MENU" how do I calculate the width and height of the Text? If I set SetBkColor() just before TextOut() to a different color than the HDC Background I see that it's rendered as a Rectangle - but how do I get the size of this rectangle and before writing out the Text on the screen?

Also, I set CreateFont() and SelectObject(HDC, Font) beforehand so I can write "bigger" text for the Menu.

Anyone with suggestions?

Haven't found a working solution for this with native GDI and not using newer Graphics objects in .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is probably `DrawText()` with `DT_CALCRECT`.

You can also measure text yourself with `GetTextExtentPoint32()`.